# Cross Network CI/CD (Dev to Prod)

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, cicd

We are currently setting up CI/CD pipeline in an air-gapped environment. The DEV and PROD network are segregated on different VLAN network and sitting in between is an app-aware firewall which only allows authorized traffic to pass through to the PROD network. The CI sits in the DEV env while the CD tool sits in the PROD env.

**What we have in DEV Network?**
Code Commit -> CI Pipeline (Build) -> Artifact Uploaded to DEV Repo -> Approval Stage (if need to deploy to PROD) -> Push Artifact to PROD Repo -> Edit a random file on PROD code repo to trigger CD pipeline

**What we have in PROD Network?**
CD Pipeline -> Approval Stage to Deploy -> Deploy to Kubernetes/VMs

**Questions**

1. What is the best practice to trigger a CD flow to run after the artifact is pushed to the PROD artifact repo?
2. We currently perform a random code commit on a code repo on the PROD side just to trigger a CD pipeline to run and pull the PROD artifact for deployment. Is this considered a workaround or are there other recommended ways about this?